# add list of strings to json object

Tags: python, json

I have a list of tags (f.e <tags>tag1*tag2</tags> or <tags></tags> ) that I want to add via an api.

The api requires:

```
payloadtw = json.dumps([
          {
            "name": "Trefwoorden",
            "value": "[\"tag1\",\"tag2\"]",
            "updateOperation": "replace"
          }
        ])
```

or when empty:

```
payloadtw = json.dumps([
          {
            "name": "Trefwoorden",
            "value": "[]",
            "updateOperation": "replace"
          }
        ])
```

but I don't know how to create the **"[\"tag1\",\"tag2\"]"** or **"[]"**

I have so far:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('essentie_metadata.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

Bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

all_results = Bs_data.findAll('record')
for child in all_results:
    print(child.find("id").text)
    if child.find("type").text == "document":
        id = child.find("id").text

        url = "https://site.nl/api/nodes/" + id + "/metadata"

        trefwoorden = child.find("trefwoorden").text.split("*")

        payloadtw = json.dumps([
          {
            "name": "Trefwoorden",
            "value": trefwoorden,
            "updateOperation": "replace"
          }
        ])

        headers = {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payloadtw)
```

Comment: How about `tag_list = ['tag1', 'tag2']; stringified = json.dumps(tag_list)`?

Comment: Yes thanks I replaced it with:

twstringified = json.dumps(trefwoorden)

        payloadtw = json.dumps([
          {
            "name": "Trefwoorden",
            "value": twstringified,
            "updateOperation": "replace"
          }
        ])


I have to look in the details to understand why, but it seems to work

Comment: It's a poor API that uses a JSON string in the JSON itself.  The API should be designed to use `"value": ["tag1", "tag2"],` or `"value": [],` if you have control over it.